# Erlang using action id, wait function is not working

Tags: exception, try-catch, throw, erlang-otp

I just tried to run a simple function in the terminal:

```
A1 = async:new(fun(Args) -> lists:seq(1, Args) end, 10).
```

It is showing the output like this: `"#Ref<0.2297416181.3164864513.214889>"` but when I try to run the `wait` function it is not working and not showing anything. I was expecting to get a result like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

Here is my full code:

```erlang
-module(async).
-export([new/2, wait/1, poll/1]).

new(Fun, Arg) ->
    Aid = make_ref(),  % Generate a unique action ID
    ComputationPid = spawn_link(fun() -> execute_computation(self(), Fun, Arg) end),
    State = {ComputationPid, none},
    erlang:put(Aid, State),
    Aid.

execute_computation(ParentPid, Fun, Arg) ->
    try
        Res = Fun(Arg),
        ParentPid ! {self(), {ok, Res}}
    catch
        throw:Ex ->
            ParentPid ! {self(), {exception, Ex}}
    end.

wait(Aid) ->
    receive
        {Aid, {ok, Res}} -> Res;
        {Aid, {exception, Ex}} -> throw(Ex)
    end.

poll(Aid) ->
    State = erlang:get(Aid),
    case State of
        undefined -> nothing;
        {_, none} -> nothing;
        {_, Result} -> Result
    end.
```

This line added in the terminal and it is not showing anything:

```
Result = async:wait(A1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you're mixing up references and pids. In your `execute_computation/3` function, you send messages with the pid as the first element of the tuple:

```
    ParentPid ! {self(), {ok, Res}}
```

But in your `wait/1` function, you're attempting to receive tuples with a reference as the first element:

```
wait(Aid) ->
    receive
        {Aid, {ok, Res}} -> Res;
        {Aid, {exception, Ex}} -> throw(Ex)
    end.
```

Another problem is that when you spawn the `execute_computation/3` call, you're trying to pass the parent pid but the `self()` call within the `fun` is the pid of the spawned process, not the parent.

To fix it, first, change how you spawn the call to `execute_computation/3` by passing the parent pid and also passing the reference:

```
    Self = self(),
    ComputationPid = spawn_link(fun() -> execute_computation(Self, Aid, Fun, Arg) end),
```

Next, fix the `execute_computation` function to take 4 arguments and to include the reference in the sent tuple:

```
execute_computation(ParentPid, Aid, Fun, Arg) ->
    try
        Res = Fun(Arg),
        ParentPid ! {self(), Aid, {ok, Res}}
    catch
        throw:Ex ->
            ParentPid ! {self(), Aid, {exception, Ex}}
    end.
```

And finally, fix `wait/1` to receive the correct tuple:

```
wait(Aid) ->
    receive
        {_Pid, Aid, {ok, Res}} -> Res;
        {_Pid, Aid, {exception, Ex}} -> throw(Ex)
    end.
```

Note that you don't appear to be using the pid of the `execute_computation/3` process that's passed in the tuple, so you might consider dropping it.

With these changes, things work as expected:

```
2> A1 = async:new(fun(Args) -> lists:seq(1, Args) end, 10).
#Ref<0.942710366.4246732815.239328>
3> async:wait(A1).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this ParentPid and self part, you explained it properly and now my concept is clear. :)